# PHP Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to create a form that when submitted will update a database that contains user's information. I am using PDO and transactions but keep getting the following error when the form is submitted

```
PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in /var/www/html/resources/memfuncs.php on line 75
```

Here is my code:

**Settings.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if ($password1 === $password2){
    updatesettings($id, $username, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
    }
}
```

I haven't included the HTML for the form, although it is also in the above file.

**memfuncs.php**

```
function updatesettings($id, $username, $first_name, $last_name, $email){
    global $db;

    $db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        // UPDATE USERNAME
        $st2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = :username WHERE id = :id");
        $st2->execute();
        $st2->bindParam (":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st2->bindParam (":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        //UPDATE FIRST + LAST NAME
        $st = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name WHERE id = :id");
        $st->execute();
        $st->bindParam (":first_name", $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindParam (":last_name", $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindParam (":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        // UPDATE Email
        $st3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET email = :email WHERE id = :id");
        $st3->execute();
        $st3->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st3->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        // COMMIT CHANGES
        $db->commit();
    } catch (Exception $error){
        $db->rollBack();
        echo "Failed: " . $error->getMessage();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is telling you precisely what you're doing wrong. Look at the order of your `prepare`,`bind` and `execute` statements.

Comment: As @MikeW says, execute() should be done after the bindParam for each "prepare" block.

Comment: FWIW you don't need three queries to make three changes to one row - you can do it in one query. You don't need transactions then, either.

Answer (score 2):

You executed to early, `execute()` should be the last thing you do after preparing and binding:

```
$st3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET email = :email WHERE id = :id");
$st3->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st3->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st3->execute();
```

So fix this in the 3 places when you `execute()`, also if you're going to catch exceptions catch `PDOException` and put `$db->beginTransaction();` in the try block because that can fail!

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the parameters before you execute the statement. It is when the statement is executed that the parameters are evaluated, so they need to be set by this point!

So your code should look like this:

```
$st2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = :username WHERE id = :id");
$st2->bindParam (":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st2->bindParam (":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st2->execute();
```

Note that `bindColumn`, which is about getting the results *from* a query, generally should be run after `execute`.