# Im trying to do an edit form in PHP but i get "Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in "

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

i'm new into php, and i'm doing a form where i can edit one or more options in my table. I'm trying with isset and !=empty but i keep getting this error " sqlstate[hy093]: invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound " and i don't know what to do, can i get some help plz.

here is my code.

```
include('./conecta.php');

            $id_tarifa = $_POST['id_tarifa'];
            $p_origen = $_POST['p_origen'];
            $p_arribo = $_POST['p_arribo'];
            $fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
            $fecha_validez = $_POST['fecha_validez'];
            $CNT = $_POST['CNT'];
            $fcl = $_POST['fcl'];
            $sobrepeso = $_POST['sobrepeso'];
            $flete = $_POST['flete'];
            $thc = $_POST['thc'];
            $blfee = $_POST['blfee'];
            $gri = $_POST['gri'];
            $transbordo = $_POST['transbordo'];
            $tiempo_estimado = $_POST['tiempo_estimado'];
            $ciatrabaja = $_POST['ciatrabaja'];

            $sql_p_arribo = "";
            $sql_p_origen = "";
            $sql_fecha_inicio = "";
            $sql_fecha_validez = "";
            $sql_CNT = "";
            $sql_fcl = "";
            $sql_sobrepeso = "";
            $sql_flete = "";
            $sql_thc = "";
            $sql_blfee = "";
            $sql_gri = "";
            $sql_transbordo = "";
            $sql_tiempo_estimado = "";
            $sql_ciatrabaja = "";

            $sql_inicio = "UPDATE `tbl_tarifa` SET ";


            if(isset($p_origen) && $p_origen != ""){
                $sql_p_origen ="`p_origen`=:p_origen, ";  
            }elseif (isset($p_arribo) && $p_arribo != ""){
                $sql_p_arribo ="`p_arribo`=p_arribo, ";
            }elseif (isset($fecha_inicio) && $fecha_inicio != ""){
                $sql_fecha_inicio = "`fecha_inicio`=:fecha_inicio, ";
            }elseif (isset($fecha_validez) && $fecha_validez != ""){
                $sql_fecha_validez = "`fecha_validez`=fecha_validez, ";
            }elseif (isset($CNT) && $CNT != ""){
                $sql_CNT = "`CNT`=:CNT, ";
            }elseif (isset($fcl) && $fcl != ""){
                $sql_fcl = "`fcl`=:fcl,";
            }elseif (isset($sobrepeso) && $sobrepeso != ""){
                $sql_sobrepeso = "`sobrepeso`=sobrepeso, ";
            }elseif (isset($flete) && $flete !=""){
                $sql_flete = "`flete`=:flete, ";
            }elseif (isset($thc) && $thc != ""){
                $sql_thc = "`thc`=:thc, ";
            }elseif (isset($blfee) && $blfee !=""){
                $sql_blfee = "`blfee`=:blfee, ";
            }elseif (isset($gri) && $gri=""){
                $sql_gri = "`gri`=:gri, ";
            }elseif (isset($transbordo) && $transbordo != ""){
                $sql_transbordo = "`transbordo`=:transbordo, ";
            }elseif (isset($tiempo_estimado) && $tiempo_estimado != ""){
                $sql_tiempo_estimado = "`tiempo_estimado`=:tiempo_estimado, ";
            }elseif (isset($ciatrabaja) && $ciatrabaja != ""){
                $sql_ciatrabaja = "`ciatrabaja`=:ciatrabaja ";
            }

            $sql_final = "WHERE `id_tarifa` = :id_tarifa";

            $sql_total = $sql_inicio.$sql_p_origen.$sql_p_arribo.$sql_fecha_inicio.$sql_fecha_validez.$sql_CNT.$sql_fcl.$sql_sobrepeso.$sql_flete.$sql_thc.$sql_blfee.$sql_gri.$sql_transbordo.$sql_tiempo_estimado.$sql_ciatrabaja;



            $db = conecta(); // this is the PDO connection

        $consulta = $sql_total;

        $resultado = $db->prepare($consulta);

        if ($resultado->execute()){
            echo '
            <head>
                <title>Registro de Embarcadores</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
            </head>

            <header>
                <div class="headerregistro">
                    <img src="img/logo_azul.png" width="536" height="53" alt="logotipo">
                    <h4>DASHBOARD ADMINISTRACION</h4>
                </div>
            </header>
            <br>
            <div class="container">
                <section class="maininscipcion row">

                    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">

                        <h3>TARIFA EDITADA CON ÉXITO</h3>
                        <br>

                        <div class="button"><a href="./dashboard.php">DASHBOARD</a></div>
                        <div class="button"><a href="./registro_tarifa.php">REGISTRAR TARIFA</a></div>


                    </div>

                </section>
            </div>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';
        }else{

            echo "--- ERROR AL EDITAR TARIFA ---";
            echo '<a href="./registro_tarifa.php">Volver a página de registro</a>';
        }
        $db = null;
        $resultado->closeCursor();
```

Comment: There are several other issues with your code besides forgetting to bind the parameters. Your logical structure for forming the SQL query is wrong. By using an `if/elseif` structure, only the first match will be handled, the rest will be ignored. `$sql_ciatrabaja` is the only part without a comma in the end, so if that part is not set / empty, your query will end up with a syntax error because of the trailing comma. Your `WHERE` clause is also never concatenated to the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you create the query you have to bind the parameters to its placeholders (those values starting with ":" in the query). After you call `prepare()` you have to bind every parameter to a variable using http://php.net/manual/it/pdostatement.bindparam.php for each parameter or passing an array to the `execute()` method http://php.net/manual/it/pdostatement.execute.php
There are other errors in your code:

- As already stated it won't work if the last value is not set (since it's the only one without a comma)
- You shouldn't use elseif otherwise only one value will be set and the others ignored
- There's no way to tell if there are no values to set (in that case it would try to execute a query like this: **UPDATE `tbl_tarifa` SET WHERE `id_tarifa` = :id_tarifa** and give an error.
- I'm not sure using isset is correct here. Usually when you submit a form you will receive every value in the form, even those that weren't changed (and since you are editing here and not creating a new value, it's easy to assume some, if not all, of these values will be already set) which means that unless you are doing some client side check all the values will be updated all the time. The check you should do is to compare the old values with the new ones, but this is way beyond the scope of this question (more than the other comments)

This should be the best way to achieve what you need:

```
 <?php 
include('./conecta.php');
//List of the parameters names. Should you add a new value in your form, you will have to put it inside this array
$valueNames=array('p_origen', 'p_arribo', 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_validez', 'CNT', 'fcl', 'sobrepeso', 'flete', 'thc', 'blfee', 'gri', 'transbordo', 'tiempo_estimado', 'ciatrabaja');
//array with values to set inside the query
$values=array();
//query string
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_tarifa` SET ";
//Check if it's the first iteration to add the comma
$first=true;
//you might need this, if there's no value to update
$set=false;
//Iterates through all the value names
foreach($valueNames as $valueName){
    //Checks wheter the value exists
    if(isset($_POST[$valueName])){
        //If it's the first value it doesn't need a comma
        $comma=$first ? " " : ", ";
        //builds the query
        $sql.=$comma."`".$valueName."`=:".$valueName." ";
        //adds the value to the array 
        $values[":".$valueName]=$_POST[$valueName];
        $first=false;
        //if at least one value is set
        $set=true;
    }
}

//adds where to the query 
$sql.= "WHERE `id_tarifa` = :id_tarifa";
$values[":id_tarifa"]=$_POST[":id_tarifa"];



$db = conecta(); // this is the PDO connection

$resultado = $db->prepare($sql);

if ($resultado->execute($values)): ?>
    <head>
        <title>Registro de Embarcadores</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    </head>

    <header>
        <div class="headerregistro">
            <img src="img/logo_azul.png" width="536" height="53" alt="logotipo">
            <h4>DASHBOARD ADMINISTRACION</h4>
        </div>
    </header>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="maininscipcion row">

            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">

                <h3>TARIFA EDITADA CON ÉXITO</h3>
                <br>

                <div class="button"><a href="./dashboard.php">DASHBOARD</a></div>
                <div class="button"><a href="./registro_tarifa.php">REGISTRAR TARIFA</a></div>


            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php else: ?>

    --- ERROR AL EDITAR TARIFA ---
    <a href="./registro_tarifa.php">Volver a página de registro</a>
<?php 
endif;
$db = null;
$resultado->closeCursor();
?>
```

It still doesn't take into account the fact that you might not have values to update but you can use the "set" variable for that. It also doesn't check if the "id_tarifa" parameter has not been passed, but it should be an easy check

Comment: Thx, this was very helpfull! perhaps a bit too advanced for me, maybe i should try to do the same with mysql_ or mysqli_ i guess i'm not that prepared to work with pdo.

Comment: I suggest you to stick with PDO actually, it's the best (and safest) way to handle database queries (unless you use an ORM like Doctrine2) and once you learn it properly you won't go back. Remember to accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

You executed to early, execute() should be the last thing you do after preparing and binding.

```
$st3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET email = :email WHERE id = :id");
$st3->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st3->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st3->execute();
```

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26349060/1577974) will help you.

Answer (score -1):

The error itself means you forgot to use actual variables in the query.  You have to either bind variables using `bindValue()` or pass them into `execute()` as array.

Comment: This still doesn't take in to account the possibility of a syntax error because of the trailing comma if `$ciatrabaja` is empty.